# How to connect ERP to magento store via Soap?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, soap-api-v2, web-services

I want to create a login for ERP in my magento store. I have created a user and role in **web services->soap/xml-RPC** how can login via soap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Endpoint:** http://(your host)/api/soap/?wsdl

**Endpoint v2:** http://(your host)/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Use soap call **login** to generate session

```
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
```

then you can use it for other calls

```
$client->call($session, 'somestuff.method', 'arg1');
```

*Full doc:*
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: where call login to generate session.

Comment: login is a regular soap call in magento wsdl. Your soap client code depends on where and how you implement it.